# Wrong JSON output from Web Api inside asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Am trying to use Web Api to output some json within an ASP.Net web forms web application. 
Below is my get method:

```
public string Get()
    {
        String paramOne = "paramOneValue";
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConStr))
            {
                try
                {
                    var command = new SqlCommand("getMyList", conn);
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramOne", paramOne);
                    conn.Open();                       
                    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        result.Add(new
                        {
                            id = reader[0],
                            val= reader[1],
                            val1= reader[2]                                
                        });
                    }
                    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
                }
                catch (SqlException sxp)
                {
                    string msg = Resource.fetchError + " " + sxp.Message;
                    return "error";
                }
            }
    }
```

and below is the Response from firebug when the method is called within an aspx page:

```
"[{\"id\":1,\"val\":\"valFromDB\",\"val1\":\"valOneFromDB\"},{\"id\":2,\"val\":\"row2ValFromDB\",\"val1\":\"row2ValOneFromDB\"}]"
```

but the weird thing is under JSON tab individual characters are being returned as in below:

```
0   "["
1   "{"
2   """
3   "i"
4   "d"
```

Anything am missing?

Comment: You can do `JSON.parse(result)` over what you get, so that you can required object structure.

Comment: I've tried that from the frontend but not working. `success:function(res) {JSON.parse(res);}`

Comment: I have tried same ( in front end), it is working - http://jsfiddle.net/Arindamnayak/oLf786fc/

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Though I have to adapt my client code to get the parsed data, which is fine.